# How do you stop Excel VBA combobox from splitting one returned record into multiple lines?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, adodb, recordset

My combobox is populated by an ADO Recordset array that works fine with more than one record and splits the fields into two columns as needed.  However, if only one record is returned, it splits the record into two lines and throws an error because the code references "Column 2". How do you keep the single record on one line?

Comment: UNION a dummy record to the bottom of your recordset and then don't add the last row to the combobox?

Comment: Thanks @HarassedDad for the suggestion -  I don't know exactly how to try this so I experimented ...
            If rs.RecordCount = 1 Then
            varFields = Array("Null1", "Null2")
            varValues = Array("00000", "00001")
It didn't work.  
My Select statement  is 'rs.Open "SELECT Master_CIF, Entity_Name FROM CRE_MasterTable WHERE CRE_MasterTable.Entity_Name LIKE  '" & txtSearch & "%'", con, adOpenDynamic'

Comment: FYI... I added the additional fields and values to the recordset.

Comment: To use UNION your SQL would have been "SELECT Master_CIF, Entity_Name FROM CRE_MasterTable WHERE CRE_MasterTable.Entity_Name LIKE '" & txtSearch & "% UNION 0 as Master_CIF, 'fred' as Entity_Name' From CRE_MasterTable'",  (using 0 and 'Fred' as dummy values)